After upgrading to Java 21 AWS ECS fargate tasks are shutting after a while
We have java application running on AWS ecs fargate on java 11 .
Now we have updated the java version to java 21 and updated the spring boot depedency version accordingly to 2.7.31 .
After deploying the application aws ecs fargate , we do not have any issue with the functionality .
But we run the performance test , the ECS tasks are shutting down and new tasks are coming .
There is not much CPU usage
There is not much memory usage on the ecs tasks.
When I login into application logs I see
SIGTERM kill singnal received and embedded tomcat is waiting to die.
Not sure what is happening.

That indicates ECS is shutting down the container for some reason. You need to look at the load balancer health checks, and also look for any shutdown reason in the ECS service console. Also, in the ECS task console, if you look at one of the stopped tasks (you have to change the filter to display all tasks, not just running tasks) it should give a stop reason.

@MarkB Thanks for the reply  , I see the health check of the ecs task is failing due to time out . The reason for time out is that the tomcat is killed. I logged into the container bash and checked logs there is on OOM error . So now I want to see thread dump , heap dump to analyse so that I can find any reason for the tomcat java process to get killed. Any info how I can generate the thread dump inside the containser . basically I am looking the cmds to put inside my docker file  , and I have updated the docker file to get install with aws cli and move any file from docker to S3.

Any thread dump or heap dump in an AWS Fargate container would be immediately deleted/destroyed as soon as the container shuts down, because Fargate uses an ephemeral file system. You need to run the same docker image locally and reproduce the issue locally to get to that sort of thing.
